# Abridged version of Kant's Critiques, especially the Critique of Pure Reason

Tags: reference-request, critique-of-pure-reason

I'm a mathematician. I'm considering reading Emmanuel Kant's famous Critique of Pure Reason to help me think. I care more about the ideas rather than the ways of his presentation, which I'm not literate enough to appreciate.

In mathematics, one does not go read historic papers from 19th century to learn linear algebra. Instead, we read textbooks that are written for pedagogical purposes where ideas are presented in more attainable, intuitive manner. Do we have such books for Critique of Pure Judgement, given its significance?

Comment: Approaching philosophy on the model of mathematics will not get you far, ideas there are inseparable from ways of presentation, and textbooks written for pedagogical purposes do not teach them, at best they give pointers to further reading and thinking. "Critique of Pure Judgement" does not exist, there is Critique of Pure Reason and Critique of Judgement, the former one is more famous.

Comment: The way to approach them after textbook (or online) summaries is reading professional commentary. Possible duplicate of [A companion or guide to Kant's Critique of Pure Reason](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37134/a-companion-or-guide-to-kants-critique-of-pure-reason)

Comment: First you may want to read the Wikipedia on Kant's "Prolegomena to any Future Metaphysics" online.  The book is also available online PDF.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolegomena_to_Any_Future_Metaphysics

Comment: It will also help to read a history of Western Philosophy in order to place Kant in context.  I suggest the one by Julian Marias which you can find at Barnes & Noble, Amazon etc

Comment: Maybe useful [Kant: A Very Short Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=-doMacgEF0YC) as well as [Kant's Theory of Knowledge: An Introduction to the Critique of Pure Reason](https://books.google.it/books?id=CZ3o31KEUikC).

Comment: I'd recommend the book on Kant by Stephen Korner. Much can be learnt from a decent philosohy dictionary. I would agree with your remark about reading original texts since Kant's main ideas may be summarised in a lot less words then he uses. It's always a judgement whether to read an original text or go straight to a commentary or summary, and of course it all depends on the details of the case at hand.     .

Comment: Jill Vance Boroker's *Kant's Critique of Pure Reason: An Introduction* is supposed to be good in terms of laying out all his vocabulary and helping guide the reader through his argument, see the review [here](https://networks.h-net.org/node/35008/reviews/45932/arens-buroker-kants-critique-pure-reason-introduction-and-geiger) for example.

Comment: As noted above, there are many good introductory texts, which can help orient you even if you decide to read the original. Much philosophy seems unnecessarily obscure, but the philosophers are struggling to clarifying or invent categories, distinctions, and relations that simply may not exist previously in the language or in "common sense." We think in language, so new thinking requires neologisms. You can get the main ideas, but reading most philosophers you can't just "get it." It's more like learning French or Italian, just slow going. Blackwell has a good Kant Dictionary in English.

Answer (score -1):

P.D. Ouspensky's [Tertium Organum](https://holybooks-lichtenbergpress.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/Tertium-Organum-by-P-D-Ouspensky.pdf) has this extract from Kant’s CPR in the starting chapter.

The entire book can be considered to be…

## Mathematico-mystical variations on the Kantian theme

> Nothing  which  is  intuited  in  space  is  a  thing  in  itself,  and  space  is  not  a  form  which  belongs  as  a  property  to  things;  but  objects  are  quite  unknown  to  us  in  themselves,  and  what  we  call  outward  objects  arc  nothing  else  but  mere  representations  of  our  sensibility,  whose  form  is  space,  but  whose  real  correlate,  the  thing  in  itself,  is  not  known  by  means  of  these  representations,  nor  ever  can  be,  but  respecting  which,  in  experience, no inquiry is ever made. . . .
>
> The  things  which  we  intuit  are  not  in  themselves  the  same  as  our  representations  of  them  in  intuition,  nor  are  their  relations  in  themselves  so  constituted  as  they  appear  to  us;  and  if  we  take  away  the  subject,  or  even  only  the  subjective  constitution of our senses in general, t hen not only the nature and relations of objects in space and time, but even space and time themselves disappear. . . .
>
> What may be the nature of objects considered as things in themselves and without reference  to  the  receptivity  of  our  sensibility  is  quite  unknown  to  us.  We  know  nothing more than our mode of perceiving them. . . . Supposing that we should carry our  empirical  intuition  [sensory  perception]  even  to  the  very  highest  degree  of  clearness,  we  should  not  thereby  advance  one  step  nearer  to  the  knowledge  of  the  constitution of objects as things in themselves. . . .
>
> To  say,  then,  that  all  our  sensibility  is  nothing  but  the  confused  representation  of  things  containing  exclusively  that  which  belongs  to  them  as  things  in  themselves,  and  this  under  an  accumulation  of  characteristic  marks  and  partial  representations  which we cannot distinguish in consciousness, is a falsification of the conception of sensibility  and  phenomenization,  which  renders  our  whole  doctrine  thereof  empty  and useless.

Is Ouspensky a serious philosopher or a mystic or a wild fantasist I'll leave you to judge .
What can be agreed upon is that he uses a math-format...

As Fact? Truth?? Allegory??? I wont *judge*

---

<sup>Following @Conifold, I suggest you edit your question to change *Judgement* to *Reason*</sup>

Comment: It is exactly this kind of "dry talking" without any examples that makes Kant unreadable. When you use a word such as "intuit", it is necessary for you to give an example so that people understand what exactly you mean.

Comment: @DanielLi I suspect Kant is 'drier' in English than German... But that is for some English-German bilingual to affrim assertively.

Comment: Looks like a good summary to me, albeit of only one issue. For myself I cannot see much point in expanding it to match the more careful and complete presentation given by Kant when the original text is available. This summary allows one to get the gist. Ouspensky is an odd character known for his misunderstanding of Gurdjieff's philosophy. He has 'mystical' leanings and sensibilities but never quite 'groks' the  message. A philosopher maybe but not a mystic except in an aspirational sense.   .

Comment: @DanielLi I am surprised that a mathematician rants about someone who writes about concepts so abstract that it is hard to give corresponding examples at all. ZxZ spaces are not exactly intuitively understood. Intuition in Kant is perceptual input not yet "understood". Also, Kant did write the Prolegomena as an introduction, which tries to gradually lead the reader from common experience to the level of abstraction the CPR starts with.

Comment: Ouspensky's, 'In Search of the Miraculous' brings forward  questions about our 'experience' of the sensible world. He points up that the typical format of our 'certainty' can be expressed as x=y, in which we never can approach knowledge of either axis without the other. It mirrors Kant's 'ding an sich'. His illustration mirrors our experience of time. He then asks us to picture a point residing on a plane, only 'flat' exists. This is equivalent to the 'present'. So the 'passage of time cannot be determined by the planar being. The point on the plain can not determine how time moves.